# topology in R infinity

Tags: general-topology, analysis

What does the following sentence mean and why is that true:

"The nonnegative orthant in $R^{\infty}$ has empty interior in product topology"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the following:

> The set $A= \{ x = ( x_i )_{i=1}^\infty \in \mathbb{R}^\infty : ( \forall i ) ( x_i \geq 0 ) \}$ has empty interior in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

It is true because the basic open sets are of the form $U = \prod_{i=1}^\infty U_i$ where each $U_i$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $U_i = \mathbb{R}$ for all but finitely many $i$.  It follows that given any nonempty open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\infty$ there is an $x = (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in U$ such that $x_i < 0$ for all but finitely many $i$, and so no nonempty open set is a subset of $A$.

---

***Edit:*** The above remarks were made under the (likely incorrect) thinking that $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is what might better be called  $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, a product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$.  Some (most?) mathematical circles would use $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ to denote the family $$\{ x = (x_i)_i \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} : x_i = 0\text{ for all but finitely many }i \}.$$  The analysis above mostly works for this set as well, but the conclusion

> It follows that given any nonempty open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\infty$ there is an $x = (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in U$ such that $x_i < 0$ for all but finitely many $i$ ...

would need to be changed to

> It follows that given any nonempty open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\infty$ there is an $x = (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in U$ such that $x_i < 0$ for some $i$ ...

(Which actually suffices for my original assumption as well!)

Comment: why are the basic open sets are of that sort? Is it a convention to define open sets with that form? Thank you

Comment: @SalihUcan: This is from the definition of the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).  Is it convention?  Yes, just as most things in mathematics are.  But it turns out that this is the definition that "works the best".